# Best Way to Convert Time String to Time Interval String

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I have an app that displays departure times in the form "5:35 PM" and I would like to add an option to display the times in the form of an interval from now, ex: "23 mins".

I am new to swift and I'm still wrapping my head around dealing with dates and the date formatter

Comment: Do you have the underlying `Date` object? If so, use `DateIntervalFormatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to extend the `Date` class to return differences - and although you only show minutes, you should be able to handle intervals like "3 days, 2 hours, 23 mins" - of course, you may choose to display that as just "3 days", or "more than 51 hours"

```
extension Date
{
    func differenceInDays(date: Date) -> Int
    {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: date).day!
    }
    func differenceInHours(date: Date) -> Int
    {
        // returns the TOTAL number of hours, not just the hour component
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: self, to: date).hour!
    }
    func differenceInMinutes(date: Date) -> Int
    {
        // returns the TOTAL number of minutes, not just the minute component
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: self, to: date).minute!
    }
}
```